# Stackdriver debug appengine error: python module not found

Tags: python, google-app-engine, debugging, stackdriver

I am trying to debug and make a capture in the Stackdriver debug appengine tool, it shows me the code, including the error line in StackDriver but when I try to make a capture after a few seconds the message appears in red: "python module not found".
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when you try to take a snapshot in source code that is not part of the executing service/version. For example when the code you are using belongs to another running service in the same project..

Please use the console Feedback tool or email cdbg-feedback@google.com with this issue.  We will help you figure this one out.

thanks,
.Erez